# What’s the meaning of “rebill” in the enclosed sentence?

Tags: meaning

> The tote in question was a “rebilled” narcotic, where there was a problem filling the tote inside the vault where they are staged due to lack of supply.

Comment: and the meaning of the whole phrase

Comment: Where is this from? What is the context? It sounds like slang usage, or maybe a typo. *Rebill* probably means to [bill](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bill) again, but there are many meanings of *bill* and it's not clear from this excerpt which meaning applies.

Comment: @StuartF It's obviously from a pharmacy. I don't see any slang.

Comment: @tchrist: That would imply ***tote*** is a slang term for *[medical] **prescription*** (a usage unknown to me). And perhaps ***rebilled*** is some loose usage referring to ***repeat prescriptions***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers No, the [tote is just some sack or bag](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/203809) that they put the meds in once they get them in stock and can bill the patient's insurance again. It's common for a pharmacy to keep all "narcotics" (actually, legally "controlled" substances like amphetamines and benzodiazepines and opioids) in a locked vault overnight, including partially filled scripts like this one, to prevent or at least deter theft.

Comment: @tchrist: Even after finding [the full context](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Effective_Interviewing_and_Interrogation/JuMzKpFu93IC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22The+tote+in+question+was+a%22&pg=PA196&printsec=frontcover), wherein there seem to be several sentences primarily concerned with expanding on the "scare-quoted" term ***rebill***, I still don't understand exactly what it means. So I'd say it's essentially "pharmacy-related domain-specific jargon". (But "tote" here sounds more like ***junkie-related jargon*** to me! :)

Comment: (cf ***baggie*** for weed / cannabis)

Comment: @FumbleFingers It's at most retail jargon, not junkie jargon: see that OED link. Why don't you know what *rebill* means as a verb?  This is just normal practice in the insane American health care system. You have to bill the insurance so that they'll pay most of the cost of the medication. But you can't bill them until you have all the medication to put in the bottle to put in the sack to put in the vault that Jack built. Sometimes when you bill the insurance it doesn't go through due to some restriction or technicality, so the next day you get all your ducks lined up and rebill them.

Comment: Is "rebill" related to sales promotion? "Jumbo was billed as the opening act, but was later rebilled as the third act".

Comment: @WeatherVane I don't see how that meaning could possibly apply to putting narcotics in bags.

Answer (score 1):

After reading the [full text](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Effective_Interviewing_and_Interrogation/JuMzKpFu93IC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22The%20tote%20in%20question%20was%20a%22&pg=PA196&printsec=frontcover), it seems like some kind of replacement or supplement when an order couldn't be filled completely. Normally the distributor fills the containers ("totes") inside a secure vault of drugs, and keeps them there until they're transferred to the delivery service. But in this case, the vault didn't have enough of the drug in question, so they couldn't fill the tote with the required drugs. Instead, the tote was filled when they were giving it to the delivery driver, and this replacement is called a "rebill".

I suspect the term has some relationship to the way pharmacies bill insurance companies.